# Why does session based upload to OneDrive fail after October 25th 2019 - using Android API

Tags: android, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Since January 2019 I have used the msgraph Android library to upload files to OneDrive using session based upload. Code below. Since October 25th however, this no longer works. The code was unchanged and 
and we have received numerous reports from users that upload fails starting that date. Direct upload ( < 4 MB ) method worked OK and still works OK.

It seems Microsoft did some migration to the new Azure portal around that date. Could it be related and that azure does not (yet) support session based uploads? Any other idea what's wrong + how to restore the session based upload?

Here's the relevant code section

```
        DriveItemUploadableProperties props = new DriveItemUploadableProperties();
        List<Option> options = new ArrayList<>();
        if (_fileInfo.isNew())
            options.add(new QueryOption("@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "rename"));
        else
            options.add(new QueryOption("@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "replace"));
        String encodedName = OneDrive.buildURLEncodedPath(_fileInfo.name());
        // This excepts with 400, bad request
        UploadSession session = OneDrive.instance().client().getMe().getDrive().getItems(_fileInfo.parentId()).getItemWithPath(encodedName).getCreateUploadSession(props).buildRequest(options).post();
                    // ** never reaches this**
        if (session != null) {
                    }
```

Here's the detailed log:

```
E/DefaultHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 333: OneDrive Service exception POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/[removed]:/Direct

%20upload%20Conflict%20Copy.smmx:/microsoft.graph.createUploadSession?%40microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior=replace
    SdkVersion : graph-android-v1.7.0
E/DefaultHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 333: Authorization : bearer [removed]
    {"item":{}}
E/DefaultHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 333: 400 : Bad Request
E/DefaultHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 333: X-Android-Selected-Protocol : http/1.1
E/DefaultHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 333: Strict-Transport-Security : max-age=31536000
    Cache-Control : private
    x-ms-ags-diagnostic : {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West Europe","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"001","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_21"}}
E/DefaultHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 333: client-request-id : [removed]
    X-Android-Response-Source : NETWORK 400
    X-Android-Sent-Millis : 1573630667766
E/DefaultHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 333: request-id : 22625e49-3b7f-466a-a75b-431a0b300c99
    Content-Length : 212
E/DefaultHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 333: X-Android-Received-Millis : 1573630668566
    Date : Wed, 13 Nov 2019 07:37:53 GMT
    Content-Type : application/json
E/DefaultHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 333: {
       "error": {
          "code": "invalidRequest",
E/DefaultHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 333:       "message": "Bad Argument",
          "innerError": {
E/DefaultHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 333:          "request-id": "[removed]",
             "date": "2019-11-13T07:37:53"
E/DefaultHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 333:       }
       }
E/DefaultHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 333: }
E/DefaultHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 333: Throwable detail: 
    com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/[removed]:/Direct%20upload%20Conflict

%20Copy.smmx:/microsoft.graph.createUploadSession?%40microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior=replace
    SdkVersion : graph-android-v1.7.0
    Authorization : bearer [removed]
    {"item":{}}

    400 : Bad Request
    [...]

    [Some information was truncated for brevity, enable debug logging for more details]
        at com.microsoft.graph.http.DefaultHttpProvider.handleErrorResponse(DefaultHttpProvider.java:357)
        at com.microsoft.graph.http.DefaultHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(DefaultHttpProvider.java:294)
        at com.microsoft.graph.http.DefaultHttpProvider.send(DefaultHttpProvider.java:190)
        at com.microsoft.graph.http.DefaultHttpProvider.send(DefaultHttpProvider.java:170)
        at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseRequest.send(BaseRequest.java:272)
        at com.microsoft.graph.generated.BaseDriveItemCreateUploadSessionRequest.post(BaseDriveItemCreateUploadSessionRequest.java:43)
        at [removed].onedrive.OneDriveFileUploader.doInBackground(OneDriveFileUploader.java:77)
        at [removed].onedrive.OneDriveFileUploader.doInBackground(OneDriveFileUploader.java:23)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:246)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1187)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the [removed] `request-id` value? That'll give more details for debugging

Comment: Done, client request-id is 22625e49-3b7f-466a-a75b-431a0b300c99

Answer (score 0):

It's not immediately obvious why you're seeing a change in behavior, but you may be able to work around it by shifting the `@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior` annotation from a query string parameter to being in the body instead:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/test.txt:/createUploadSession

{
  "item": {
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "replace"
  }
}
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0#request-body